# Telerik RadGrid not displaying

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have this radgrid that appears to be getting data but it is not displaying. After binding the grid.Items.Count is set to the number of rows expected.I'll includ the ajax manager settings and grid. One note if interested. In the onRequestStart javascript I'm just doing some client-side validation. Thanks!

Here's the appropiate snippets:

```
 <telerik:radajaxmanager id="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server"> 
         <clientevents onrequeststart="onRequestStart" />
        <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadBtnRetrieve">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadPanelBar1" loadingpanelid="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                <telerik:ajaxupdatedcontrol controlid="RadAjaxPanel1" loadingpanelid="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGridPartsWashers">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGridPartsWashers" loadingpanelid="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:radajaxmanager>



 <telerik:radajaxpanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" loadingpanelid="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" enableajax="true">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridPartsWashers" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True"
                        CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        CssClass="RadGrid.rgMasterTable" onneeddatasource="RadGridPartsWashers_NeedDataSource">
                        <ClientSettings>
                            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
                            <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" ScrollHeight="" UseStaticHeaders="True"></Scrolling>
                            <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" />
                        </ClientSettings>
                        <MasterTableView EnableHeaderContextMenu="true" EnableNoRecordsTemplate="true" DataKeyNames="AssetNumber"
                            EnableSplitHeaderText="true" TableLayout="Auto" Width="100%">
                            <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" />
                            <NoRecordsTemplate>
                                <div>
                                    There are no records to display
                                </div>
                            </NoRecordsTemplate>
                            <Columns>
                              .....
                             </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the telerik samples
      public partial class DefaultCS : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    LoadData();
                }
            }

```
        protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged(object source, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            RadGrid1.DataSource = GetDataTable("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, PostalCode FROM Customers");
        }

        protected void RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        protected void RadGrid1_SortCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
        {
            String ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return myDataTable;
        }
    }
```

Did you forget to put RadGrid1.DataBind?

Regards,
Hugo Pedrosa

Comment: Thanks Hugo but that isn't the issue. It's being bound, I can see the items collection with the data. It's not displaying. I'm guessing it has something to do with the wiring of the ajax panels but it escapes me.